# RPI problems with surveillance on USB devices

Tags: usb, mount, rtsp

I configured my raspberry 4B as a video surveillance system with ffmpeg that captures rtsp streams from 8 IP cameras set at 4Mb of bitrate. Before, I used a NAS, until the ethernet controller failed and was replaced by an SSD mounted in a USB3.0 box connected to the relative USB3.0 port of the rpi4.

Everything seemed to work without problems, until I noticed two anomalies that did not manifest themselves with the NAS:

1. Checking the system log with the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog` often shows these errors:

   Jan 13 01:22:44 living-room kernel: [160785.567037] EXT4-fs (sda1): previous I / O error to superblock detected
   Jan 13 01:22:44 living-room kernel: [160785.569799] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_find_entry: 1450: inode # 43930662: comm sftp-server: reading directory lblock 0

The following errors also appear with other new ssd drives, both with FS ext4 and xfs. Instead trying with a traditional hard disk the error is not shown.

2. Another anomaly is the consumption of ram. In fact, during the acquisition I noticed with `top` that the buffer/cache value increases more and more until leaving only 70/80MB of ram free. The value remains the same even if I interrupt the acquisition, but it resets only if I delete the folder for the recordings or if I unmount the USB drive.

I speculated that both problems could be attributed to a bad mount in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sda1 /home/pi/Storage ext4 x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

I tried to add some options like noatime and sync without solving anything.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Unused RAM is wasted RAM. Memory being allocated for filesystem cache is good, don't worry about it. [Clickety click](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/). What power supply are you using to power the Pi? Does the external drive enclosure have a separate power supply?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I use a usb 3.0 2.5" box powered by raspberry via usb. The raspberry 4b is powered by a good quality compatible 5v 3a power supply. All tried hd and ssd are obviously 2.5" and the box used is always the same. However, I know that SSDs use less energy, how is it possible that I only detected the problems with them?

Comment: i don't know why HDDs don't exhibit this behavior for you, but RPis are very sensitive to voltage fluctuations and notoriously damage filesystems. I'd consider connecting the drive through a powered USB hub or using a beefier power supply.